# Enabling address sanitizer for a plugin

Tags: xcode, debugging, address-sanitizer

I am building a plugin for a third party over which I have no control. I'd like to use the Address Sanitizer with Xcode 7 with this plugin. I can successfully compile my plugin and install it. The problem is that I am unable to prove it is working. I am including the following piece of code to make sure the sanitizer detects a problem :

```
int* test = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
free(test);
*test = 5;
NSLog(@"%d", *test);
```

When the third party application loads my plugin, the expected crash never occurs and the number 5 gets logged.

I have used the `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH` environment variable to prove the address sanitizer runtime library was loaded and sure enough, it was :

```
dyld: loaded: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
```

Is there any way I can make this diagnostic tool work on a plugin when the main executable isn't using it?

Comment: The only workaround I have found is to create an emulator for the software that usually loads the plugin. This way I can activate the Address Sanitizer in both binaries and the diagnostic tools starts reporting problems in the plugin.